# ¿Es posible mostrar una imagen desde un campo TextField()?

Tags: django, django-models

¿puedo mostrar imágenes insertando el enlace en un campo TextField()??

El enlace a la imagen si funciona pero cuando lo inserto  en el cuerpo del post (variable *text = models.TextField()*) me aparece como texto únicamente. ¿Es que con TextField() no puede realizarse esto o que la falla esté en algún otro lado?

[image: postear imagen en Django]

En caso de no ser posible si pueden orientar como puede hacerse.

Comment: @toledano el filtro `safe` fué la solución a este problema como bien comentaste. Muchas gracias!! Igual creo que es la misma solución pero una pregunta diferente. Lo dejo a su consideración si debe cerrarse.

Answer (score 0):

Con el campo Textfield() si puede agregarse una imagen insertando el código HTML correspondiente `<img src="enlace" />`

pero al hacer esto debe sumarse el filtro `safe` al código del template. ejemplo:

> {{ var|safe|escape }}

como aquí se indica en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#safe). De lo contrario Django escapa por seguridad.